# SQL count records if only type x exists on date or other types if other than type x exists on date

Tags: t-sql, date, sql-server-2008-r2, count, case

On SQL SERVER 2008 R2 I have the following table:

- `event_id` int
- `people_id` int
- `event_date` date
- `event_type` varchar

`event_type` may be :

- `"encounter"`
- `"legal"`
- `"food"`
- `"job_search"`
- `"education"`
- `"utilities"`
- `"child_care"`

I wish to count events.

BUT I wish to count "encounter" event_type ONLY if it is the only event_type recorded for that people_id/event_date combination.

If there is another event_type for that people_id/event_date combination, I want to count all the event_type s for that people_id/event_date combination that are not event_type "encounter".

I wish to return a count of all events, given the above conditions, for the date range `YEAR(event_date) = 2013`

I've found other solutions using `SUM(CASE WHEN ...) AS x` and that appears to be the way to go here, but I'm thrown when combining this with counting only types other than `"encounter"` if `"encounter"` and any other `event_type` appears for the same date/person OR other `event_type` appears for the same date/person without type `"encounter"`.

Any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can break your query into 2 parts one for only 'encounter' and one for others:

```
select ...
where event_type='encounter'
group by ...
having count(event_type)=1

Union

select count(event_type),...
where event_type <> 'encounter'
group by ...
having count(event_type)>1
```

Comment: Thank you ram_sql!  I tried approaching with a UNION and this seemed to be the best result.